# how to count a list of numbers which occour in a random list Python

Tags: python, random

I run 1000 times of random.choice()from a list from 0-11. how to track of the number of random selections necessary before all 12 number have been selected at least once. (Many will be selected more than once.)
For instance, suppose the simulation yields the following sequence of random choices for a single
trial: 2 5 6 8 2 9 11 10 6 3 1 9 7 10 0 7 0 7 4, where all 12 numbers have been selected at least once. The count for this example trial is 19. Collect the count for each trial of the
simulation in a single list (ultimately consisting of 1,000 counts).

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  What have you tried so far?  What difficulties are you running into?

Comment: List what you tried so far and we can help troubleshoot that.

Comment: mylist=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
sequence=[random.choice(mylist) for i in range(1000)]
list=[]
if mylist in sequence:
    list.append(mylist)

Comment: my trouble is how to count these numbers occour once in this sequence list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `collections.Counter` as a container:

```
from collections import Counter
import random

nums = list(range(12))
n = 1000
counts = [0]*n
for trial in range(n):
    c = Counter()
    while len(c)<len(nums):
        c[random.choice(nums)]+=1
    counts[trial] = sum(c.values()) # c.total() in python ≥ 3.10

counts
```

Output:

```
[28, 24, 39, 27, 40, 36, ...] # 1000 elements
```

Distribution of the counts:

[image: histogram of counts]

Comment: Nice use of Counter; I didn't know there was a `.total()` function added to it.

Comment: This is new in python 3.10

Comment: I have a new question about this. if i want to use random.choices(nums, weights), how can i get this worked

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using a set to store your results in a non-redundant way, while checking to see if all numbers have been used:

```
import random

guesses = set()
count = 0
for i in range(1000):
    count += 1
    guesses.add(random.randrange(0, 12))
    if len(guesses) == 12:
        break
print(count)
```

This will give you 1 count. A better method is outlined by mozway in their answer.

You can run the code a million times and collect the results in a list, then graph it like so (updated with a `while` condition):

```
import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

counts = []
for i in range(100000):
    guesses = set()
    count = 0
    while len(guesses) != 12:
        count += 1
        guesses.add(random.randrange(0, 12))

    counts.append(count)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
x = np.array([i for i in range(np.max(np.array(counts)))])
y = np.array([counts.count(i) for i in range(np.max(np.array(counts)))])
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Number of Guesses')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

[image]

So `[counts.count(i) for i in range(np.max(np.array(counts)))]` is going to give you a list of how often the guessing game finished for that given position of the list. I.e. the first value of the list is 0, because there is no way that the game can finish with only 1 guess, but at position 25 (25 guesses) there are over 2000 instances of that happening

Comment: Thank you! what if I want to get a list of  how many item in each counts

Comment: IIUC the question, this answer produces only one count, while OP expects 1000

Comment: Yes you're right, my initial answer was for a single loop and I think during your comment I edited my answer to include a cycle through a million, which isn't what OP wants either. Your answer with the while loop is technically better!

Comment: :D I just added an histogram for fun and realized you did the same, great minds think alike :p +1

Comment: Any excuse for a histogram and I'm sold (although mine's just a vanilla bar chart) ;)

Comment: Thank you all! You guys are awsome! I really need some time to study your code.